# What sock_net() does?

Tags: sockets, kernel

I was studying the communication between user-space and kernel by reading a kernel module that does this, but in the code there is a call to the function sock_net() which I didn't understand. I searched a lot but I didn't found any documentation about this particular function, so what this function actually does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It returns the network stack object the socket belongs to, if the network namespace is enabled (a container often has its own network).

See https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/net/sock.h#L2503:

```
static inline
struct net *sock_net(const struct sock *sk)
{
    return read_pnet(&sk->sk_net);
}
```

Where [`read_pnet`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/net/net_namespace.h#L322) is:

```
static inline struct net *read_pnet(const possible_net_t *pnet)
{
#ifdef CONFIG_NET_NS
    return pnet->net;
#else
    return &init_net;
#endif
}
```